# jQuery - remove style attribute on window resize

Tags: jquery, css

I have used this site for a long time and have learned a significant deal of awesome stuff, but this is the first time I'm asking a question as I can't seem to find any other questions that answer it.

Basically what I am trying to do is this: on my site we have a 'promo banner' element which sits above the main content block on all pages. The banner contains some promotional text that has remained static for a long time, so the top margin of the main content block has been set based on that static height.

However now we have added new content to the banner which is going to be regularly changed, and it is causing the banner to expand to double its usual height, causing it to cover a small part of the main content block. I could fix this with additional media queries, however I don't want to be adjusting those every single time we change the content.

So I wrote this little jQuery script to find out if the banner has expanded to two lines, and if so, adjust the top margin of the main content block so it doesn't get covered up.

```
//Check if promo banner has expanded to two lines and adjust container margins accordingly
$(window).load(function() {

  function bannerHeight() {
    var $banner = $('.promo-banner');
    if($banner.height() > 30) {
      $('.main-content').css('margin-top',117+'px');
    }
  }
  // Execute on load
  bannerHeight();
  // Execute when window is resized
  $(window).resize(bannerHeight);

});
```

This is currently working perfectly on page load and when resizing the window down, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove the jQuery-added style attribute when the window is resized up to a point where the banner goes back to one line, so that the margin can revert back to what is in the stylesheet.

I hope this all makes sense, if anyone has any advice it would be a massive help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest the use of `classes`. Create a class like `.addedMargin` with the following css style: `margin-top:117px!important /*might not need the !important*/`;

```
//Check if promo banner has expanded to two lines and adjust container margins accordingly

$(window).load(function() {

  function bannerHeight() {
    var $banner = $('.promo-banner');
    if($banner.height() > 30) {
        $('.main-content').addClass('addedMargin');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.main-content').removeClass('addedMargin');
    }
  }
  // Execute on load
  bannerHeight();
  // Execute when window is resized
  $(window).resize(bannerHeight);

});
```

This way you can add multiple styles easily and remove them when no longer needed.

Comment: Geez, I obviously need another coffee, I cannot believe I didn't think of that! So simple! Thanks so much JanR

Comment: No problem , glad it helped